# How filter array of objects by another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need to filter array of object by another array of object without knowledge of exact properties in `criterias` array. Let's take a look to example for better understanding.

Here is an array that I need to filter

```
const dataset = [
{
  id: "4",
  someval1: "10",
  someval2: "20",
  someval3: "30",
  someval4: "40"
},
{
  id: "10",
  someval1: "10",
  someval2: "20",
  someval3: "30",
  someval4: "40"
},
{
  id: "22",
  someval1: "102",
  someval2: "202",
  someval3: "302",
  someval4: "40"
}];
```

Here is an array which has values that are supposed to be filter condition for first array

```
const criterias = [{ someval1: "10" }, { someval3: "30" }, { someval4: "40" }];
```

So whenever object in `dataset` contains all values from `criterias` I want to keep him. Problem is that I want objects in dataset to be filtered by all `criterias` that are equal.

So far I was able to get this script which filters `dataset` correctly but only by one `criteria`. So from given arrays after filtering I should get only first two objects from `dataset`, third one does not meat all `criterias`.

Here is my current script

```js
const dataset = [
{
  id: "4",
  someval1: "10",
  someval2: "20",
  someval3: "30",
  someval4: "40"
},
{
  id: "10",
  someval1: "10",
  someval2: "20",
  someval3: "30",
  someval4: "40"
},
{
  id: "22",
  someval1: "102",
  someval2: "202",
  someval3: "302",
  someval4: "40"
}];

const criterias = [{ someval1: "10" }, { someval3: "30" }, { someval4: "40" }];

const filter = dataset.filter(item => criterias.some(criteria => Object.keys(criteria).some(prop => item[prop] != criteria[prop])));

console.log(filter)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the entries of the condensed object and use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and check the properties with the values.

```js
var dataset = [{ id: "4", someval1: "10", someval2: "20", someval3: "30", someval4: "40" }, { id: "10", someval1: "10", someval2: "20", someval3: "30", someval4: "40" }, { id: "22", someval1: "102", someval2: "202", someval3: "302", someval4: "40" }],
    criterias = [{ someval1: "10" }, { someval3: "30" }, { someval4: "40" }],
    filters = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...criterias)),
    result = dataset.filter(o => filters.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina could you give, please, a  link where it is possible to read about this interesting syntax `([k, v]) =>` ? I mean why do we use square brackets? What do they mean?

Comment: it is part of a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the paramter list of a function. [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) retuns an array of key/value pairs in nested arrays. to get a key and value, you could destructure an entrie and get the items by iterating the entries of the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter()` and `Array.every()`:

1. `Array.filter()` will filter the matched object and put those in a new array.
2. `Array.every()` will be used for checking that every object in `criterias` array satisfies the object of `dataset`. Since there could be any name for the object key in object of `criterias` array, you can use `Object.keys()[0]` to get that particular key as you only have one key in each object of `criterias` array.

```js
const dataset = [{
    id: "4",
    someval1: "10",
    someval2: "20",
    someval3: "30",
    someval4: "40"
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    someval1: "10",
    someval2: "20",
    someval3: "30",
    someval4: "40"
  },
  {
    id: "22",
    someval1: "102",
    someval2: "202",
    someval3: "302",
    someval4: "40"
  }
];

const criterias = [{
  someval1: "10"
}, {
  someval3: "30"
}, {
  someval4: "40"
}];

let result = dataset.filter((datasetObj) => criterias.every((criteria) => criteria[Object.keys(criteria)[0]] === datasetObj[Object.keys(criteria)[0]]));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Array.prototype.every` for the `criterias` array to check and validate all the criteria objects to the item in the `dataset`:

```js
   var dataset = [
{
  id: "4",
  someval1: "10",
  someval2: "20",
  someval3: "30",
  someval4: "40"
},
{
  id: "10",
  someval1: "10",
  someval2: "20",
  someval3: "30",
  someval4: "40"
},
{
  id: "22",
  someval1: "102",
  someval2: "202",
  someval3: "302",
  someval4: "40"
}];

var criterias = [{ someval1: "10" }, { someval3: "30" }, { someval4: "40" }];
var res = dataset.filter(item => 
        criterias.every(criteria => 
          Object.keys(criteria).every(prop => 
            item[prop] == criteria[prop])));
console.log(res)
```