# Filter array of objects matching values from second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

In my react app I have users that look like this:

```
{ username: 'admin', genres: [{name: 'Music', id: 1}, {name: 'Art', id: 2}] }
```

And videos that look like this:

```
{ title: 'cool video', genres: [{name: 'Music', id: 1}, {name: 'Technology', id: 3}] }
```

I am trying to write a function that will return an array of the video objects that contain any of the genres inside a single user. So far I have been able to hard code a solution, but it breaks if a user has the wrong number of genres, so I am looking for a neater solution. This is what I have so far:

```
function filterVideos() {

const userGenres = []

user.genres.forEach(genre => {
  userGenres.push(genre.name)
})

const filteredVideos = videos.filter(video => {

  return video.genres.find(o => o.name === userGenres[0])
   || video.genres.find(o => o.name === userGenres[1])
   || video.genres.find(o => o.name === userGenres[2])
})
return filteredVideos}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How filter array of objects by another array of objects \[ES6\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133504/how-filter-array-of-objects-by-another-array-of-objects-es6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are looking to return a filtered array of complete video objects which have at least one genre in common with the passed user.

You can simplify the user's genre array to an array of genre names using a single `map()` call.

```
const userGenres = user.genres.map(({name}) => name);
```

It is then a matter of using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine if any of the video's genres are included in the `userGenres` array using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
 videos.filter(video => (
    video.genres.some(({name}) => userGenres.includes(name))
  ));
```

```js
const user = { 
  username: 'admin',
  genres: [{name: 'Music', id: 1}, {name: 'Art', id: 2}] }

const videos = [
  {
    title: 'video1', 
    genres: [{name: 'Music', id: 1}, {name: 'Technology', id: 3}] 
  },
  {
    title: 'video2', 
    genres: [{name: 'Art', id: 1}, {name: 'Technology', id: 3}] 
  },
  {
    title: 'video3', 
    genres: [{name: 'Sports', id: 1}, {name: 'Technology', id: 3}, , {name: 'Skiing', id: 3}] 
  }
]

function filterVideos(user, videos) {

  const userGenres = user.genres.map(({name}) => name);
  
  return videos.filter(video => (
    video.genres.some(({name}) => userGenres.includes(name))
  ));
  
}

console.log(filterVideos(user, videos));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `some()` inside `filter`

```
const filteredVideos = videos.filter(video => user.genres.some(gen => gen.name === video.name))
```

```js
const user = { username: 'admin', genres: [{name: 'Music', id: 1}, {name: 'Art', id: 2}] }
const video = { title: 'cool video', genres: [{name: 'Music', id: 1}, {name: 'Technology', id: 3}] };

const res = video.genres.filter(v => user.genres.some(g => g.name === v.name));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: you can use `id` instead of `name`. I think it might be better idea

Comment: @AlexeyZelenin Your point is valid but OP requirement is to compare `name`

Comment: Are you sure about the `user` part?because i think he has an array of `users` not a single `user` object?

Comment: @AlanOmar I was also thinking of that but he didn't mentioned anything yet. I just refactored his come into simpler. Lets see how OP respond

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys! I think id or name would have been viable, but I was looking to return the whole video object as in Pilchard's solution! (I probably didn't do a great job of explaining myself!) Really appreciate the help though! :)